# Math Stack Exchange reputation bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

There seems to be some problem with my reputation. I have received 2 upvotes and the OP accepted my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259063/big-o-interpretation/259074#259074), but this is not reflected on my account.

Answer (score 12):

As Mad Scientist wrote, you didn't get reputation because your large number of edits turned the answer into community wiki.

All I can say about your [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6894/math-stack-exchange-reputation-bug#comment25069_6895) is that [*caveat emptor*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts): you joined a community and this community has its rules.

That said, we have pretty [standard ways of dealing with 'undeserved' automatic conversions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1798/1543) on this site. In the future you can just flag your post for moderator attention with a request to de-wikify. We will look over the edit history and make a judgment call. If, as in this case, your edits were *bona fide* attempts to improve the mathematics (and in your case many are just barely outside the 5-minute successive edit interval) instead of 'excessive bumping', we would remove the CW status from the post (and also protect it from future automatic conversions).

---

Of course, one way to avoid all these hassles is to make sure each edit fixes as much as possible. (That is, make large edits in batches instead of many small incremental ones.) That said, we are only human.

Comment: (Oh, I just noticed that it is not entirely clear from the third paragraph that I've reverted the CW change on the OP's post.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have not gained any reputation. Also, [moderators cannot see my flags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/moderators-ignoring-flags), which is another problem with Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: Try visiting the page http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation scroll to the bottom, and trigger a recalculation. If that doesn't work, send an e-mail to team+math@stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

The answer has been automatically converted to community wiki because it has been edited more than 10 times. This means you won't gain any further reputation from this post.

This is not a bug, but an intentional feature designed to discourage excessive bumping of posts to the frontpage. It's not a very intelligent mechanism though, and can't distinguish between a user heavily updating their post multiple times, and a user making irrelevant changed to bump a post.

Comment: Why can I not gain reputation from community wiki? Gerry Myerson gained reputation from [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good/71882#71882) community wiki.

Comment: You don't gain reputation from community posts in general, but you still get reputation for the time before the post was converted to CW.

Comment: I think it is quite pointless.

Comment: @glebovg: That's the point... CW posts *are* pointless :-)

Comment: For good and sufficient reasons, the rules that apply to the rest of you do not apply to me.

Answer (score 1):

Reputation takes a while to update sometimes where wiki status is concerned.

In your case... your second reputation recalc did the job:

[image]

You can also see the rep changes in your [reputation history](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/36367/glebovg?tab=reputation):

[image]